# Graphing a complex equation

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Identify (i.e., name of the shape) and  graph the equation.

$|z-1|+|z+1|\leq 2$

Work done so far:

Since $z$ is a complex number assume: $z=x+iy$
$$|x+iy-1|+|x+iy+1|\leq 2$$
Since if $z=x+iy$, then $|z|=\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$
$$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}\leq 2$$

After this I am completely lost. Please feel free to correct any errors in calculations and show me how to answer this sort of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(x-1)^2+y^2=r^2$ defines a circle with center $(1,0)$ and radius $r$, similarly for the second expression with center $(-1,0)$. You can also think of the first expression as the euclidean distance of a point $(x,y)$ from $(1,0)$ and similarly for the second with distance of a point $(x,y)$ from $(-1,0)$. You want the sum of these distances to be less than or equal to 2. Let us pick the point $(0,0)$, it is equidistant from both centers and the sum of the distances is 2. I argue that due to the triangle inequality you cannot get a better distance, that is the only solutions is $(1-\lambda)(-1,0) + \lambda(1,0), \lambda \in [0,1]$ (it lies on a straight line between the two centers, imagine having a string and you can stretch it, moving away away on $y$ will only yield a greater distance). So to prove the convex linear combination, we set $y=0$ (since it will only increase the distance and thus violate the inequality if it's not 0). Then $\sqrt{(x-1)^2} + \sqrt{(x+1)^2} = 2|x|$, then $x \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!